# pip: How to install into /usr/local

Tags: python, installation, pip

If I run `pip install` as root, I want it to install into `/usr/local`.

This works on some linux systems, but on others it does not.

How can I force pip to install into my desired directory?

A solution using a config file would be preferred to a solution with a command line argument.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1308714

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should create config file $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf and add option:

```
[global]
target = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

And add this directory to your PYTHONPATH if it isn't in. Add to $HOME/.bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-t

Comment: This does not work. Yes, it installs into /usr/local. But Python does not find it. It needs to be under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. I updated your answer. ok?

Comment: It's ok, I've edited answer too, so you can change directory path to arbitrary.